# Does Belo Horizonte airport have an international transit area?

Tags: airports, transit-visas, brazil

I'm considering an international connecting flight via Belo Horizonte airport.

Does transiting at this airport require a visa? Is there in international transit area?

What does the international transit process look like? My layover would only be one hour.

Comment: Until I know, you will need to go to immigration and customs in all Brazil airport. Belo Horizonte airport is not so crowded, so it could be fine.

Comment: According to Timatic, "Transiting without a visa is possible for: Passengers with a connecting flight booked on the same ticket in transit," but that doesn't say anything about whether you have to clear immigration anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm hoping for a more specific answer, but here's what the airline, Azul Linhas Aereas Brasileiras, replied:

> As Brazil and Argentina have a territory agreement in South America, you will just make a short connection in Belo Horizonte, with no need of new customs.

**Post-travel update:**

There was a ground agent at the end of the jetway upon arrival. I asked what to do for my international connection and was told to wait with there with them. They then started calling out "Orlando" (the apparent only international transit destination) to try and find other transit passengers. They located two other passengers and brought us up a staircase and unlocked the door into the international departure lounge. Very straightforward and only took a couple minutes.